# Create a hadoop jar with external dependencies using Gradle

Tags: build, hadoop, gradle

How do I create a hadoop jar that includes all dependencies in the lib folder using Gradle? Basically, similar to what fatjar does.

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out! Hadoop looks for libraries inside the "lib" folder of the final jar. So, add the following to the "jar" task.

```
 jar {
     doFirst {
         into('lib') {
             from configurations.runtime
         }
     }
 }
```